# Phpstorm: xdebug and an unknown file call

Tags: php, xdebug, phpstorm

I have Phpstorm 3.0.2 and I've been trying to configure the debugger for some time now. I get it to work when I use the bookmarklets and setup "debug this site", but when I use the IDE's "debug" button I get stumped at this error:

```
Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

The commandline run is:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req "C:\Documents and Settings\<User>\Local Settings\Temp\ide-phpunit.php" --no-configuration <project-folder>
```

I don't know why ide-phpunit.php is called, what is it supposed to do (other than something with the ide and phpunit!) and so forth. This setup has been modified by my "predecessor" so there might be some quirks in the environment setup by them.

Why does it try to run phpunit-things and how can I disable it? In case I can't, how do I make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are creating **wrong** Run/Debug Configuration type entry.

You creating "PHPUnit" one, while you need "PHP Web Application" or "PHP Remote Debug".

1. **Run | Edit Configurations ...**
2. Create correct one manually here

Comment: Thank you very much. I understad the question was stupid, but the answer helped a ton!